# Add two input fields by JavaScript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have these three input fields in my form

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">             
        <label for="ot" class="col-sm-4 control-label">OT Duration:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input class="form-control" name="ot" type="text" id="ot">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">             
        <label for="ot_rate" class="col-sm-4 control-label">OT Rate/Hour:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input class="form-control" name="ot_rate" type="text" id="ot_rate">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">  
       <label for="ot_bill" class="col-sm-4 control-label">OT Amount:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input class="form-control" name="ot_bill" type="text" id="ot_bill">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to add values of `ot` and `ot_rate` to `ot_bill` when `ot` or `ot_rate` is `onblur` and value of `ot` and `ot_rate` is greater than zero.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Share your JS code.

Comment: What do you mean by `onblure` ?

Comment: @StefanBaiu I didn't try anything yet.

Comment: @AGE `onblur` means when the cursor move on from these input fields.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: @smartrahat ah so it's 'onblur' not onblure

Comment: @AGE Yes brother, I have corrected my spelling. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly your question the solution can be:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#ot, #ot_rate').blur(function() {
    var ot = (isNaN($('#ot').val()) == true || $('#ot').val().trim().length == 0) ? -1 :  parseInt($('#ot').val());
    var otrate = (isNaN($('#ot_rate').val()) == true  || $('#ot_rate').val().trim().length == 0) ? -1 :  parseInt($('#ot_rate').val());
    if (ot > 0 && otrate > 0)
      $('#ot_bill').val(ot + otrate);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ot" class="col-sm-4 control-label">OT Duration:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input class="form-control" name="ot" type="text" id="ot">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ot_rate" class="col-sm-4 control-label">OT Rate/Hour:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input class="form-control" name="ot_rate" type="text" id="ot_rate">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ot_bill" class="col-sm-4 control-label">OT Amount:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <input class="form-control" name="ot_bill" type="text" id="ot_bill">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe type="text" will only return a string. This should be using parseInt.

Comment: The result is coming `2+2=22` I think `+` is working as `concatenate`

Comment: @smartrahat Sorry but this evening it seems I am sleeping...try now

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code :

```
<input class="form-control" name="ot" type="text" id="ot" onblur="updateValue()">
<input class="form-control" name="ot_rate" type="text" id="ot_rate" onblur="updateValue()">
<input class="form-control" name="ot_bill" type="text" id="ot_bill">
<script>
function updateValue(){
    var ot = parseInt($("ot").val());
    var ot_rate = parseInt($("ot_rate").val());

    if(ot > 0 && ot_rate > 0){
        var total = parseInt(ot) + parseInt(ot_rate);
        $("#ot_bill").val(total);
    }
}
</script>
```